# Multiple $PORT on Heroku Docker deployment

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile, dgraph

The current deployment Dockerfile contains this

```
CMD ["sh","-c","dgraph zero --my=0.0.0.0:5080 & dgraph alpha --my=0.0.0.0:7080 --zero=0.0.0.0:5080"]
```

However since Heroku dynamically allocates ports, they recommend the $PORT variable.
But when substituted, all the ports get the same number.

Is there anyway to have more than one $PORT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not possible**: every Web Dyno exposes only one port which is provided at runtime with the `$PORT` env variable.

You can deploy each component into its own Dyno (they will then communicate over HTTPS).

Or you could look at [Heroku Private Spaces](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-enterprise#heroku-private-spaces) which is an enterprise feature.